# Passing in "self" as a parameter in function call in a class (Python)

Tags: python, class

I defined a class and within that class, created some methods. In one of the methods I wish to call another method. What is the reason that I cannot call the method by placing "self" into the argument? For example, method2(self).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are languages that let you write `method2()` as a shorthand for (what in Python would be) `self.method2()`, but you can't in Python. Python doesn't treat the `self` argument as special inside the function <sup>(except when calling `super()`)</sup>.

In Python, `method2(self)` first of all looks up `method2` in the current scope. It seems like it should be in scope, but it actually isn't because of Python's weird scoping rules. Nothing in any `class` scope is ever visible in nested scopes:

```
x = 1

class A:
    x = 2

    print(x)  # prints 2

    def method(self):
        print(x)  # prints 1

    class B:
        print(x)  # prints 1
```

Even if `method2` was in scope, calling it directly would call the method from the class currently being defined, not the overridden method appropriate to the dynamic type of `self`. To call that, you must write `self.method2()`.

Comment: could you explain what you mean by "dynamic type of self"?

Answer (score 1):

The `self` parameter is automatically passed in as the object you are calling the method from. So if I said `self.method2()`, it automatically figures out that it is calling `self.method2(self)`

Comment: `self.method2(self)` is not the same as `self.method2()`.

Comment: For normal methods, `self.method()` is equivalent to `type(self).method(self)`, I'm guessing that's what you were trying to write.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a method with `self` as an argument, but in this case the method should be called as the method of the class, not the instance.

```py
class A:
    def method1(self):
        print(1)

    def method2(self):
        A.method1(self)

a = A()
a.method2()
# 1
```